# Mean of Nested Lists

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to calculate the mean of nested lists. I have tried using the map function, but the default gives the mean in the opposite dimension that I am interested in. See the below example:

```
set a [[1 1][2 2][3 3]] ; create a nested list
set b map mean a        ; b equals [1 2 3]
```

This answer gives `[1 2 3]` for b. However I am interested in the answer `[2 2]` by taking the mean in the "other" dimension. I would imagine there is a way to do this with `map` but haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
to go
  print column-means [
    [ 1 1 ]
    [ 2 2 ]
    [ 3 3 ]
  ]
end

to-report column-means [ matrix ]
  if length (remove-duplicates map length matrix) > 1 [
    error "All rows must be the same length"
  ]  
  report n-values length first matrix [ mean extract ? matrix ]
end

to-report extract [ i row ]
  report map [ item i ? ] row
end
```

Comment: Thanks to @Bryan Head for suggesting to use `extract ? matrix` directly in `n-values` instead of adding a separate `map` step.

Comment: Also note that this code could be made simpler if/when https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/773 is implemented.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is the following

`set a [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]]`
`set b map mean a`

this will give you `[2 2]` for b.

Comment: What i mean is that if you imagine a matrix 3x2, instead of defining a as the 3 row-vectors you could define a as the two column-vectors...in this way you get the "mean in the opposite dimension"

Comment: I agree this would work, except I'm not sure if the nested list could be built that way because the nested list is built from lists that the agents own.